# Autofilter between dates in a column + another criteria not populating destination

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data table (Sheet named BI_Comissoes), where I got Date Column and a Salesman Column. Then, I got the destination sheet, which serves as a report to be populated based on a date range entered on B7 and B8 and the salesman's name entered on B5.
Once run the code, destination sheet doesn't get populated, but the data sheet gets filtered normally. 
The code was working before, but I guess I messed with it somewhere and my neurons seem to be burned out, as I can't find out where the problem is.

I've tried many date formats, but nothing seems to work. For your information, the date on Data Table comes as dd/mm/yyyy.

```
Sub SelectDataBetweenTwoDates()
    'declare variables
    Dim fromDate, toDate As Date
    Dim MyResults As Worksheet, MyData As Worksheet, MyDates As Worksheet

    Set MyResults = Worksheets("Relatório de Comissão")
    Set MyData = Worksheets("BI_Comissoes")
    Set MyDates = Worksheets("Relatório de Comissão")

    'clear previous results
    'MyResults.Cells.Clear

    'attribute date values to variables
    fromDate = MyDates.Range("B7").Value
    toDate = MyDates.Range("B8").Value
    Vendedor = MyResults.Range("B5").Value

    'convert to text format to allow filtering
    fromDate = Format(fromDate, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
    toDate = Format(toDate, "dd-mmm-yyyy")

    'clear previous filtered data
    With MyResults
    'If fromDate = "" Or toDate = "" Then
        'MsgBox "Informar o período!"
        'Exit Sub
    'Else: Resume
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Number = 0
    .Range("A$17:$K$20000").Select
    Intersect(Selection, _
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)).ClearContents
    End With

    With MyData
    'removes autofilter
            If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData

    'filter the data based on selected date values
    lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("$B$2:$B$" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
                ">=" & fromDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & toDate
            .Range("G$2:G" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Vendedor

    'copy the filtered data
            .Range("$B$2:$B$30000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            MyResults.Range("A17").PasteSpecial _
            Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    End With

    'Informs the user, incase nothing has been parsed into the results table
    If MyResults.Range("A17").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Não há comissão neste período."
    End If

    'brings selection to the main cell
    MyResults.Activate
    MyResults.Range("B5").Select

    End Sub
```

The purpose is to have A17:K populated based on the date range and salesman entered.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your date in `double` **to avoid** this kind of error : `Autofilter()` works with *universal* format `yyyy-mm-dd`. Here your format is quite different so VBA miss interpret your dates (2 january would be read as 1 february for example)

```
Criteria1:= ">=" & CDbl(fromDate), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CDbl(toDate)
```

So your code would be :

```
Sub SelectDataBetweenTwoDates()
    'declare variables
    Dim fromDate, toDate As Date
    Dim MyResults As Worksheet, MyData As Worksheet, MyDates As Worksheet

    Set MyResults = Worksheets("Relatório de Comissão")
    Set MyData = Worksheets("BI_Comissoes")
    Set MyDates = Worksheets("Relatório de Comissão")

    'clear previous results
    'MyResults.Cells.Clear

    'attribute date values to variables
    fromDate = MyDates.Range("B7").Value
    toDate = MyDates.Range("B8").Value
    Vendedor = MyResults.Range("B5").Value

   '**THIS** is the part I commented out, since these are declared as Date, thus compatible with the data I'm trying to filter. Then, there was no need to convert it to string for filtering purposes. 
    'convert to text format to allow filtering
    'fromDate = Format(fromDate, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
    'toDate = Format(toDate, "dd-mmm-yyyy")

    'clear previous filtered data
    With MyResults
    'If fromDate = "" Or toDate = "" Then
        'MsgBox "Informar o período!"
        'Exit Sub
    'Else: Resume
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Number = 0
    .Range("A$17:$K$20000").Select
    Intersect(Selection, _
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)).ClearContents
    End With

    With MyData
    'removes autofilter
            If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData

    'filter the data based on selected date values
    lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("$B$2:$B$" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
                ">=" & CDbl(fromDate), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CDbl(toDate)
            .Range("G$2:G" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Vendedor

    'copy the filtered data
            .Range("$B$2:$B$30000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            MyResults.Range("A17").PasteSpecial _
            Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    End With

    'Informs the user, incase nothing has been parsed into the results table
    If MyResults.Range("A17").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Não há comissão neste período."
    End If

    'brings selection to the main cell
    MyResults.Activate
    MyResults.Range("B5").Select

    End Sub
```

Don't hesitate to leave me feedbacks so I can improve my answer if needed.

Maybe read [this](http://www.oaltd.co.uk/ExcelProgRef/Ch22/ProgRefCh22.htm) can help you to avoid those kind of error.

Kindest regards

Comment: Hello @Dorian!
I tried it, but it now gives me rows containing dates out of the range typed on B7 and B8, curiously. I am playing around with the data format to check where the root cause might be... Any idea as to where I should be headed? Thanks!

Comment: @AntonioSantos try to debug.print date as long format and see if vba read the date as excepted

Comment: I believe I will have to accept mine as the solution, since excluding the conversions si what solved the issue. Don't you think? :)

Comment: Pouvez-vous mettre le commentaire que j'ai fait sûr la conversión que n'est pas necessaire, s'il vous plaît? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

At the end, here is how I've solved it, in case anyone runs into this kind of issue:

```
Sub SelectDataBetweenTwoDates()

'declare variables
    Dim fromDate, toDate As Date
    Dim MyResults As Worksheet, MyData As Worksheet, MyDates As Worksheet

    Set MyResults = Worksheets("Relatório de Comissão")
    Set MyData = Worksheets("BI_Comissoes")
    Set MyDates = Worksheets("Relatório de Comissão")

'attribute date values to variables
    fromDate = MyDates.Range("B7").Value
    toDate = MyDates.Range("B8").Value
    Vendedor = MyResults.Range("B5").Value

'**THIS** is the part I commented out, since these are declared as Date, thus compatible with the data I'm trying to filter. Then, there was no need to convert it to string for filtering purposes.    
'convert to text format to allow filtering
    'fromDate = Format(fromDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    'toDate = Format(toDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    'MsgBox fromDate

    'clear previous filtered data
   With MyResults
    If fromDate = 0 Or toDate = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Informar o período!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Number = 0
    .Range("A$17:$K$20000").Select
    Intersect(Selection, _
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)).ClearContents
    End If
    End With

    With MyData
    'removes autofilter
            If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData

    'filter the data based on selected date values
    lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("$B$2:$B$" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
                ">=" & CDbl(fromDate), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CDbl(toDate)
            .Range("G$2:G" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Vendedor
```